# Can I bind a key to a macro without applying it on an action button?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

So far all I can do is to create a macro, place it on an action button, and make sure that this action bar has a key bound to it. But now I'm running out of action buttons.

I would like to bind a key (or a key combination) to a macro without the need for an action button.

Thanks.

Comment: Before I write up an answer, because there are several solutions (The short version: you need an addon), let me ask: Do you currently use an Action Bar mod such as Dominos, Bartender, Macaroon, or another? Or a full UI package like TukUI? If so, which?

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz -- nope; everything is stock. I would like to keep it like that, if possible.

Comment: If you'd like to not run any addons, you're SOL.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz -- that's what I was afraid of.  OK, what would I use if I'm ok with addons?  Would I have to use a whole different action-bar UI?  I hope not =(.  _Minimalism_ is the keyword here; I've had bad experiences with a addons in the past.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a solution that has been tested. This solution assumes that all the action bars are not in use nor shown:

- Go in to the *Interface* menu then set an hidden action bar to show.
- Next add an action or macro to that bar.
- Once the action has been added to the bar, go in to the built in *Key Binding* option menu, find the bar and action-button combo that you just set the action to, then bind the wanted key to that combo.
- Once finished, go back in to the *Interface* menu, set the bar to hide then test it out.

If all of the action bars are shown then there is a second solution. However, this solution does requires a addon called [**Clique**](https://www.curseforge.com/wow/addons/clique). Clique is an addon, which is very popular among players, that allows spells and actions to be bound to keys and mouse-clicks without the use of an action bar. Clique doesn't change the physical UI of the normal view. It only adds another tab to the spell book. Go in to the tab, bind the a action to a key or mouse button and forget about it.

*After reading the body of your question again, I believe the first solution is the current solution you use. However, I will not remove that part of the answer as it might help a future user with a similar question.*

Comment: +1 for Clique addon. It really is minimalistic. You won't even notice it's there other than setting up your keybindings at first. Extra bonus: doesn't take up macro slots!

Comment: that was spot-on!  **Clique** is exactly what @Mag said; minimalistic like I need, and no macro/action button slots needed.  +1!

Answer (score 7):

You can bind a macro to a key without an addon using [SetBindingMacro](https://warcraft.wiki.gg/wiki/API_SetBindingMacro) followed by SaveBindings.

> `/run SetBindingMacro("SHIFT-A", "mymacro")`
> `/run SaveBindings(2)`

Replace `SHIFT-A` with whatever key you want: `A`, `ALT-A`, `CTRL-SHIFT-A`, etc.
Replace `mymacro` with the name you gave your macro.
Replace the `2` in the `SaveBindings` call to a `1` if you do not have character specific key bindings. If you are playing Classic rather than Retail, use [`AttemptToSaveBindings`](https://warcraft.wiki.gg/wiki/API_SaveBindings) instead of `SaveBindings`.

`SetBindingSpell` can be used similarly to bind spells.

Comment: I... did not know you could do this. Amazing.